# Windows 10 Quick Access Change default view to details

Tags: view, directory, windows-10, default

For a long time, I had the view of the Quick access link in windows 10 showing as Details.
Recently it changed to Tiles which I hate. Of course, I changed it to details but every time it comes back and shows tiles. It does that while in the same session and also after rebooting.
I read about some solutions that require very complex changes to the registry which I feel reluctant to do.

Does anyone have a workable solution to change the default view of the Quick access that will stick?
Thanks

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 0):

I called Microsoft help support. They connected to my computer via quick assist and did NOTHING, and the issue is resolved. I asked the agent if they did any changed to my computer and she said NO. So strange.
Here is the email received from MS
Hello,

Thank you for contacting Microsoft Windows Tech Support.

Here are the steps we did to resolve your issue in this interaction:

- When I did Quick assist, when customer opened File explorer noticed that was exactly how he wanted it to be.
- Closed Quick assist, restarted PC and it was working again.